# How to force flexbox to 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I am making my first web application. It is my first time working with html/css/js. This seems to be a common question/issue with css, but I have trouble understanding/making the solution work. This is the closest I've gotten.

I am struggling to make the app (specifically `wrapper` or `body`) encompass only the height of the page (no more or less).

If there is little content, `content` doesn't extend all the way down and the `footer` is at the middle of the page. Although, adding `height: 100%;` to `html` seems to fix this.

If I add a lot of lines to `calendar` or `sidebar`, a scroll bar is added to the whole page instead of only `calendar` or `sidebar`. `height: 100%;` in `html` doesn't seem to fix this.

The width for `content` seems to work well.

I have tried changing the height for `body` and `wrapper` but it doesn't seem to do anything?

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to body doesn't seem to work either.

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  text-align: left;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#sidebar {
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  background-color: #00e7eb;
}

#calendar {
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #c8eed6;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Journal</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1 id="currentCalendar">Quarter</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <h4>Calendars</h4>
        <button>+ Add Calendar</button>

        <h4>Classes</h4>
        <button>+ Add Class</button>

        <h4>Tags</h4>
        <button>+ Add Tags</button>
      </div>

      <div id="calendar">
        <p>No calendar. Click '+ Add Calendar' to make new calendar.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <p>dg</p>
      <button>Donate</button>
    </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: overflow:auto to #content

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `min-height: 100vh;`. Should be noted though, 100vh can be tricky when it comes to mobile depending on your design. You can also try

`html, body { min-height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height: 100vh;` to the target element.

Answer (score 0):

in CSS height % values only work if the parent container has a set height. So if you want to adjust the main body to 100% display height you can do:

```
    body{
      height: 100vh; /*viewport-height=100% of screen height*/
   }
```

and then you can set the first child of that to 100%

Comment: 100% was no misstake.

Comment: wasn't clear tho before you added the "you can also try", all good tho!

Comment: I think that was there from the start, no worries :)